# java.lang.ClassCastException while sending Parcelable[] as Intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending an array of `TutorAccount` as an intent extra to another Activity. Here are the TutorAccount and Account classes involved:

```
public class TutorAccount extends Account{

    public TutorAccount(TutorProfile profile) {
        super(profile);
    }

    public TutorAccount(TutorProfile profile, LocationInfo locationInfo) {
        super(profile, locationInfo);
    }

    public TutorProfile getProfile() {
        return (TutorProfile) super.getProfile();
    }

    public void setProfile(TutorProfile profile) {
        super.setProfile(profile);
    }
}
```

and the Account class,

```
public class Account implements Parcelable {

    /**Email Id of the User */
    private String mEmailID;

    /**Important to have the status indexed as this shall be used during a query for a particular user type*/
    private Integer accountStatus;

    // Profile info.
    private GenericLearnerProfile profile;

    // Tutor's location info. - this would be computed from {Latitude, Longitude} which shall be available
    // from the _1 info. Also, this holds a reference to the LatLng{Latitude, Longitude} from the _1.
    private LocationInfo locationInfo;

    public Account(GenericLearnerProfile profile) {
        if(profile == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Profile can't be null");
        }
        this.profile = profile;
        mEmailID = profile.getEmailID();
        // Auto boxing
        this.accountStatus = profile.getCurrentStatus();
    }

    public Account(GenericLearnerProfile profile, LocationInfo locationInfo) {
        if(profile == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Profile can't be null");
        }
        this.profile = profile;
        this.locationInfo = locationInfo;

        mEmailID = profile.getEmailID();

        this.accountStatus = profile.getCurrentStatus();
    }

    private Account(){

    }

    public GenericLearnerProfile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(GenericLearnerProfile profile) {
        if(profile == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Profile can't be null");
        }
        this.profile = profile;
        mEmailID = profile.getEmailID();
    }

    public LocationInfo getLocationInfo() {
        return locationInfo;
    }

    public void setLocationInfo(LocationInfo locationInfo) {
        this.locationInfo = locationInfo;
    }

    public static class LocationInfo implements Parcelable {
        private String shortFormattedAddress;

        public LocationInfo(String shortFormattedAddress) {
            this.shortFormattedAddress = shortFormattedAddress;
        }

        public String getShortFormattedAddress() {
            return shortFormattedAddress;
        }

        public void setShortFormattedAddress(String shortFormattedAddress) {
            this.shortFormattedAddress = shortFormattedAddress;
        }

        protected LocationInfo(Parcel in) {
            shortFormattedAddress = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(shortFormattedAddress);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<LocationInfo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LocationInfo>() {
            @Override
            public LocationInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new LocationInfo(in);
            }

            @Override
            public LocationInfo[] newArray(int size) {
                return new LocationInfo[size];
            }
        };
    }

    protected Account(Parcel in) {
        mEmailID = in.readString();
        accountStatus = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
        profile = (GenericLearnerProfile) in.readValue(GenericLearnerProfile.class.getClassLoader());
        locationInfo = (LocationInfo) in.readValue(LocationInfo.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mEmailID);
        if (accountStatus == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeInt(accountStatus);
        }
        dest.writeValue(profile);
        dest.writeValue(locationInfo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Account> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Account>() {
        @Override
        public Account createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Account(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Account[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Account[size];
        }
    };
}
```

You can see that `TutorAccount` extends `Account`. Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.learncity.generic.learner.account.Account cannot be cast to com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount
                      at com.learncity.learner.search.SearchResultsActivity.onCreate(SearchResultsActivity.java:48)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It is saying Account cannot be casted to TutorAccount. I am not sure how Account even came into casting scenarion as it is supposed to be Parcelable to TutorAccount cast.

Here is the code used to send and receive the Intent extra:

**Sending Activity**

```
// Show these accounts in a list view
Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
i.putExtra(SEARCHED_ACCOUNTS, refactorAccountsToArray(accounts));
startActivity(i);
```

**Receiving Activity**

```
List<TutorAccount> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
        for(Parcelable p : getIntent ().getParcelableArrayExtra(SEARCHED_ACCOUNTS)){
            list.add((TutorAccount)p);
        }
```

I have tried Logging the p - the Parcelable in the receiving activity and it shows it being an instance of Account. I am not sure how this is happening. Has anyone faced this?

**EDIT:**

The `List<TutorAccount> accounts` that I am receiving in the argument here is a different class to model backend JSON data.

Here is the `refactorAccountsToArray()` method:

```
private List<com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount> refactorAccountsToList(List<TutorAccount> accounts){
        // Extract the list of accounts from backend
        List<TutorProfileVer1> profiles = new ArrayList<TutorProfileVer1>();
        List<Account.LocationInfo> locationInfos = new ArrayList<Account.LocationInfo>();
        for(TutorAccount acc : accounts){
            profiles.add(acc.getProfile());
            locationInfos.add(new Account.LocationInfo((acc.getLocationInfo() == null ? null: acc.getLocationInfo().getShortFormattedAddress())));
        }

        // Populate a profile model
        List<com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount> acc = new ArrayList<com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount>();
        List<TutorProfile> refactoredProfiles = TutorProfile.populateProfilesFromEntities(profiles);
        int i = 0;
        for(TutorProfile p : refactoredProfiles){
            com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount t = new com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount(p);
            t.setLocationInfo(new Account.LocationInfo(locationInfos.get(i).getShortFormattedAddress()));
            acc.add(t);
            i++;
        }
        return acc;
    }

    private com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount[] refactorAccountsToArray(List<TutorAccount> accounts){

        List<com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount> refactoredProfiles = refactorAccountsToList(accounts);
        return refactoredProfiles.toArray(new com.learncity.tutor.account.TutorAccount[refactoredProfiles.size()]);
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can understand from your code, you are passing list of Account objects (accounts), but then in receiving Activity, you are trying to cast them to TutorAccount. Because the objects are not of type TutorAccount, but an Account, this gives you cast error.

Comment: what does `refactorAccountsToArray(accounts)` return? show it's code.

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun : I have written and checked code to talk with TutorAccount only and not Account as you can see through the methods I have added in the Edit.

Comment: @VladMatvienko : Posted the code.

Comment: I am not 100% shure, but try to add CREATOR, writeToParcel and parcel constructor to your TutorAccount class. It seems to me that Parcelable uses the one of Account class, so "unparceled" objects will be of Account type, not TutorAccount. Please, update the TutorAccount class so we can see code you've added.

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun : Your suggestion worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the advice by **@AnhaytAnanun** Turns out that for even a cast, a creator is required for a Parcelable entity. My code works now with the inclusion of CREATOR and other Parcelable methods. Here is the revised code:

```
package com.learncity.tutor.account;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.learncity.generic.learner.account.Account;
import com.learncity.tutor.account.profile.model.TutorProfile;

/**
 * Created by DJ on 3/7/2017.
 */

public class TutorAccount extends Account{

    public TutorAccount(TutorProfile profile) {
        super(profile);
    }

    public TutorAccount(TutorProfile profile, LocationInfo locationInfo) {
        super(profile, locationInfo);
    }

    public TutorProfile getProfile() {
        return (TutorProfile) super.getProfile();
    }

    public void setProfile(TutorProfile profile) {
        super.setProfile(profile);
    }

    public TutorAccount(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<TutorAccount> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TutorAccount>() {
        @Override
        public TutorAccount createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TutorAccount(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TutorAccount[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TutorAccount[size];
        }
    };
}
```